# Combined Bar plots in python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, graph

I have a grouped `dataframe` which is this:

```
            Speed (mph)
Label Hour             
5     13      18.439730
      14      24.959555
      15      33.912493
7     13      23.397055
      14      18.497228
      15      33.493978
12    13      32.851146
      14      33.187193
      15      32.597150
14    13      14.491841
      14      12.397724
      15      19.581669
21    13      34.985289
      14      34.817009
      15      34.888187
26    13      35.813901
      14      36.622450
      15      36.540348
28    13      33.761174
      14      33.951116
      15      33.736014
29    13      34.545862
      14      34.227974
      15      34.435377
```

I am trying to plot bar plots where each bar is grouped by their `Label` and `Hour`

- An example:

[image]

The above graph is just an example I found on the internet. I don't really need the lines and the numbers over the bars.

---

I tried plotting like this:

```
newdf.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

which gives me -

[image]

---

- *Question*

How can I plot the graph so that `Label:5,Hour:13,14,15` and close to gether, then some space and then `Label:7,Hour:13,14,15` close together and so on?

Comment: So the question is who is willing to type all that dataframe manually into his editor to be able to provide a solution? Please read [ask], [mcve] and clearly state in how far other questions here did not help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to unstack

```
df.unstack().plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can show your thankfulness towards the community by not ever again asking a question without runnable example.

Comment: I did, immediately change the dataframe.png to code